# Trouble using NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to minimize five function at the same time. I am running in some trouble minimizing this function, as since I am not that familiar with Mathematica I really do not know what I am doing wrong. I recive this error message, which honestly do not understand. Did I something wrong with my functions?

```
NMinimize::nnum: The function value (0.0278102 -Pattern[-0.606562,_] Pattern[-0.389209,_]-Pattern[-0.229482,_] Pattern[0.239269,_]-Pattern[-0.527577,_] Pattern[0.247594,_]-Pattern[0.141852,_] Pattern[0.323594,_]-Pattern[-0.280859,_] Pattern[0.34209,_]-Pattern[-0.7207,_] Pattern[0.489279,_]-Pattern[-0.40525,_] Pattern[0.501551,_]-Pattern[0.421928,_] Pattern[0.519791,_])^2+(<<1>>)^2+(0.00308076 -Pattern[-0.389209,_] Pattern[0.0211036,_]-<<1>> <<1>>-<<1>>-Pattern[-0.527577,_] <<1>>-Pattern[0.219956,_] Pattern[0.586964,_])^2+(<<1>>)^2+(0.0196843 -Pattern[-0.800202,_] Pattern[-0.7207,_]-a46 Pattern[-0.40525,_]-Pattern[-0.323194,_] Pattern[0.239269,_]-Pattern[-<<19>>,_] <<1>>-Pattern[-0.46653,_] Pattern[0.323594,_]-Pattern[0.219956,_] Pattern[0.610511,_]-Pattern[-0.389209,_] Pattern[0.760863,_])^2 is not a number at {a11,a12,a15,a21,a22,a24,a25,a31,a34,a35,<<30>>} = {0.247594,0.474569,0.530488,0.21861,-0.595761,0.34209,0.270219,0.489279,0.373491,0.627177,<<30>>}.
```

Here is my code:

```
    Clear[sumsq]
I17 = 0.003080764;
I18 = 0.027810195;
I19 = 0.199365892;
I20 = 0.750058868;
I21 = 0.01968428;


eq1 = (I17 - (x1*a12 + x4*a43 + x3*a34 + x6*a64 + x9*a94))^2;
eq2 = (I18 - (x1*a11 + x4*a42 + x7*a73 + x3*a31 + x6*a63 + x2*a24 + 
       x5*a54 + x8*a84))^2;
eq3 = (I19 - (x1*a15 + x3*a31 + x6*a62 + x9*a93 + x2*a22 + x5*a53 + 
       x7*a75 + x4*a46))^2;
eq4 = (I20 - (x7*a71 + x1*x16 + x4*a45 + x6*a61 + x3*a35 + x2*a21 + 
       x5*a52 + x8*a86))^2;
eq5 = (I21 - (x7*a75 + x4*a46 + x9*a91 + x3*a36 + x6*a66 + x5*a51 + 
       x2*a25))^2;

sumsq[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_, a11_, a12_, a15_, 
  a21_, a22_, a24_, a25_, a31_, a34_, a35_, a36_, a42_, a43_, a45_, 
  a51_, a52_, a53_, a54_, a61_, a62_, a63_, a64_, a66_, a71_, a73_, 
  a75_, a84_, a86_, a91_, a93_, a94_] = eq1 + eq2 + eq3 + eq4 + eq5
sol = NMinimize[
  sumsq[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_, a11_, a12_, a15_,
    a21_, a22_, a24_, a25_, a31_, a34_, a35_, a36_, a42_, a43_, a45_, 
   a51_, a52_, a53_, a54_, a61_, a62_, a63_, a64_, a66_, a71_, a73_, 
   a75_, a84_, a86_, a91_, a93_, a94_], {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, 
   x8, x9, a11, a12, a15, a21, a22, a24, a25, a31, a34, a35, a36, a42,
    a43, a45, a51, a52, a53, a54, a61, a62, a63, a64, a66, a71, a73, 
   a75, a84, a86, a91, a93, a94}, Method -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Try `sol = NMinimize[eq1 + eq2 + eq3 + eq4 + eq5, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, a11, a12, a15, a21, a22, a24, a25, a31, a34, a35, a36, a42, a43, a45, a51, a52, a53, a54, a61, a62, a63, a64, a66, a71, a73, a75, a84, a86, a91, a93, a94}]` ,although it may be difficult to minimize over so many variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the variables are in

```
DeleteDuplicates@Catenate[Variables /@ {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}]
```

Or

```
Variables[eq1 + eq2 + eq3 + eq4 + eq5]
```

and the function should be `sumsq[x1,x2,...]` instead of `sumsq[x1_,x2_,...]`

```
I17 = 0.003080764;
I18 = 0.027810195;
I19 = 0.199365892;
I20 = 0.750058868;
I21 = 0.01968428;


eq1 = (I17 - (x1*a12 + x4*a43 + x3*a34 + x6*a64 + x9*a94))^2;
eq2 = (I18 - (x1*a11 + x4*a42 + x7*a73 + x3*a31 + x6*a63 + x2*a24 + 
       x5*a54 + x8*a84))^2;
eq3 = (I19 - (x1*a15 + x3*a31 + x6*a62 + x9*a93 + x2*a22 + x5*a53 + 
       x7*a75 + x4*a46))^2;
eq4 = (I20 - (x7*a71 + x1*x16 + x4*a45 + x6*a61 + x3*a35 + x2*a21 + 
       x5*a52 + x8*a86))^2;
eq5 = (I21 - (x7*a75 + x4*a46 + x9*a91 + x3*a36 + x6*a66 + x5*a51 + 
       x2*a25))^2;
sol = NMinimize[eq1 + eq2 + eq3 + eq4 + eq5, 
  Variables[eq1 + eq2 + eq3 + eq4 + eq5]]
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Can constraints be added in the same way, using constraints?

Comment: Okay, I simply tried it, it works, thanks!

Comment: @Zorg Yes, for example when we add a new constraint  eq6, `eq6 = (a - b)^2;
f = Total[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}];
sol = NMinimize[f, Variables[f]]`